# How to enable 3rd party software

Tags: 16.04, software-center, software-sources

After I upgraded Ubuntu, I can't use my 3rd-party apps like Steam and Skype and so on.

I tried to look up how I can turn it on again, but the last information I could find was for Ubuntu 12.10 and I'm on 16.04, so the Software Center doesn't look the same anymore.

Can anybody can help me?

Comment: What does "can't use" mean? Can't install? Can't start? Any error messages?

Answer (score 6):

Open **Software and Updates** and go to the "Other Software" tab.  You will see your ppas all unchecked and labeled as "disabled on upgrade to xenial".

Just check the boxes and hit close. It will want to reload the information - let it - and then you can reinstall your software.

If you want to get rid of the line saying "disabled" you can highlight the ppa and hit edit.  Make the change in the comment box.

This will work unless the ppas do not exist for 16.04