# How to enable Third Party Software after upgrade from Ubuntu 16.01 to 16.10

Tags: upgrade, updates, 16.10

*****HOW I SOLVED MY PROBLEM****

What I did, I went to the shop where I got the tablet from and told them my problem, and he worked on it for a bit, and handed it back to me, problem solved. He didn't really tell me what he did, something like I had to reinstall it all...???!!????

Anyhow it works, and will be careful not to download updates if I'm not on WiFi!!

---

After upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 16.10 I was told I can enable third party software after installation. (Since they where disabled during upgrade)

I am not a geek, so much of this is greek to me..
I saw in the answer to this thread [[How to enable 3rd party software [closed]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799546/how-to-enable-3rd-party-software) what to do, but after I ticked all the boxes and hit add, I got this msg:
Enter the complete APT line of the repository that you want to add as source
The APT line includes the type, location and components of a repository, for example  'deb http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety main'.

What do I do here?

After searching on the internet I found this:[How to Install Third Party Software in Ubuntu Software Center](https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-third-party-software-in-ubuntu-software-center/) If I followed the instructions there exactly would that work for me? If so I don't understand 3. Install the application
Now, you can open Ubuntu Software Center and search for the application that you want to install.  ??

Many thanks for any help!!
Karina

Comment: What third party software/repositories you had?

Comment: Would you be kind to explain what you meant with the last paragraph? You seem to have copied and pasted parts of the MakeTechEasier article.

Comment: @xangua There are i.e. Recommended updates, unsupported updates, Canonical Partners (software packaged by Canonical for their partners), Also one says Disabled on upgrade to yakkety./ http://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_16.04/ (this one I left the tick on when I turned it off and suddenly MEGAsync is working. There are others as well which are named Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 'Xenial Xerus' Restricted software....  Do you think I can just tick the boxes and ignore that it wants me to give a ATP line.../

Comment: @luisgonzalez Yes I presumed that who read my post would check the links. I just cut/paste the #3 from that article where it said after you had done everything in his post to add the aplication from the Software Center. Thing is I don't really know what it is I'm to install. I thought the 3rd party software are just small programs that start working after I tick the boxes... sorry for being daft!!